# Boot issues, is my SSD broken?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, boot

I'm having problems with 3 month old desktop. I dual-booted Windows and Ubuntu, which worked fine for a while. After a new Ubuntu installation, it started throwing boot-loops. I thought the problem was solved after repairing the system from a Windows 11 live usb.

Last week I started having boot problems again. Repair attempts from said live usb threw various BSODs. I tried re-installing Windows, and got the following message:

"Windows installation encountered an unexpected error. Verify that the installation sources are accessible, and restart the installation. Error code: 0xC0000005"

I formatted the drive, same result. I tried wiping the drive from command prompt using diskpart, same result.

Booting from usb would work only 1/3 of the time. Booting into BIOS is no problem.
Trying to install Ubuntu gave me following, several times: "The installer encountered an error copying files to the hard disk: [Errno 5] Input/output error. This is often due to a faulty CD/DVD disk or drive, or a faulty hard disk ...[etc]".

I then wiped the drive from the linux live usb, using dd. Booting from usb works normally since then. Installing Ubuntu Budgie worked, but threw me this error: "ubi-partman failed with exit code 10". I selected "try again", no more errors.

Now, booting works sometimes. Just now, it gave me this:

```
[   0.511271] Initramfs unpacking failed: ZSTD-compressed data is corrupt
[   1.636248] usb 1-3: device descriptor read/64, error -71
/init: line 73: wait-for-boot: not found
/init: line 872: logsave: not found
the root filesystem on /dev/nvme0n1p2 requires a manual fsck

BusyBox v1.30.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.30.1-7ubuntu3) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

(initramfs)
```

So, from live usb, `sudo fsck /dev/nvme0n1` returns

```
fsck from util-linux 2.37.2
e2fsck 1.46.5 (30-Dec-2021)
ext2fs_open2: Bad magic number in super-block
fsck.ext2: Superblock invalid, trying backup blocks...
fsck.ext2: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/nvme0n1

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
 or
    e2fsck -b 32768 <device>

Found a gpt partition table in /dev/nvme0n1
```

Running suggested commands gives the exact same result.

`sudo fsck /dev/nvme0n1p2` returns

```
e2fsck 1.46.5 (30-Dec-2021)
/dev/nvme0n1p2: clean, 260182/62480384 files, 7726839/249919744 blocks
```

And before that, shutting down gave me a [systemd segfault](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0kKI4.jpg)

I'm way out of my depth here, any help would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: You could try a tool like CrystalDiskInfo (or GSmartControl in linux?) to check the smart data statistics and see how badly it's failing to read/write. Those types of I/O errors while reading/copying files usually means it's just about toasted though